# Soma de arrays retorna somente um valor

Tags: javascript, lógica

Há algum tempo precisei executar uma soma de arrays com javascript, Exemplo:

```
allData[0].likes = [5,10,15,20,25];
allData[1].likes = [10,2,3,17,15];
```

Utilizando uma solução que achei na internet utilizei o seguinte código modificado por mim mesmo:

```
var result = allData.reduce(function(array1, array2) {
        return array2["likes"].map(function(value, index) {
          return parseInt(value) + (parseInt(array1[index]) || 0);
        }, 0);
      }, []);
```

E com isso ele retornava sempre um único array, neste exemplo o valor de "result" seria: [15,12,18,37,40]

Estava funcionando perfeitamente até este Mês em que no seguinte caso abaixo ele me retorna somente uma valor em vez de um array.

```
allData[0].likes = [8,10,15,20,25];
allData[1].likes = [20];
```

Neste caso ele me retorna somente o valor 28 e ignora o resto dos valores

Como altero meu código para que isso não aconteça?

Comment: nesse `array2[likes]` o `likes` deveria estar como string, certo? desta forma `array2["likes"]`.

Comment: Isso eu tive que deletar muitos dados por questão de confidencialidade da empresa mas sim é desse jeito mesmo, ja arrumei no edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi o problema é por conta da diferença do tamanho do array. Ajustando o tamanho dos array pode resolver o seu problema sem ter que alterar o que já existe, apenas incluíndo um pequeno trecho para fazer este ajuste:

```js
let allData = [];
allData.push({ likes: [] });
allData.push({ likes: [] });

allData[0].likes = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25];
// allData[1].likes = [10,2,3,17,15];
allData[1].likes = [20];

// Analisa o array e pega o maior tamanho de array
const maxLength = Math.max(...
  allData.map(a => a.likes.length)
);

// Agora faz o ajuste para que todos os arrays tenham
// o mesmo tamanho
allData.forEach(item => item.likes = [...item.likes, ...new Array(maxLength - item.likes.length).fill(0)]);

var result = allData.reduce(function(array1, array2) {
  return array2["likes"].map(function(value, index) {
    return parseInt(value) + (parseInt(array1[index]) || 0);
  }, 0);
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Esqueci de te agradecer, muito obrigado depois que dei uma leve modificada funcionou.